# Multiple Network Interfaces

Tags: networking, connection

I have an industrial computer running with Ubuntu 14.04. This computer has two cable interfaces corresponding to **ONE** network cards. One of the cable interfaces is used to connect to a camera and the other to the Ethercat, a module to control hardware such as motors. So in Ubuntu, there are two interfaces (for wired network) in the network connection indicator, i.e., eth0 (for Ethercat) and eth1 (for camera). Every time I boot my computer, eth0 is connected automatically but eht1 is not. And I have to click eth1 manually for connection. Note that when the computer boots, the camera and the Ethercat are automatically powered on, so Ubuntu is able to detect these two connections.

So my problem is, why Ubuntu cannot connect both of eth0 and eth1 at the same time? Do different network connections interfere with each other?

In addition, this computer has wireless capability as well. So when the computer boots up, it connects to Wi-Fi automatically. That is, wlan0 is connected automatically. So I am really confused about why eth0 and wlan0 is connected automatically while eth1 CANNOT?

Added:
The output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet    
          ............
          Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1880116 errors:58 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:58
          TX packets:1885495 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:296746691 (296.7 MB)  TX bytes:297503606 (297.5 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet    
          ......
          Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13335958 errors:63 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:63
          TX packets:8334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20065444530 (20.0 GB)  TX bytes:559158 (559.1 KB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          ....
          Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1878324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1878324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:19632989941 (19.6 GB)  TX bytes:19632989941 (19.6 GB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  
          ........
          Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:85884 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:189767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7801132 (7.8 MB)  TX bytes:40101802 (40.1 MB)
```

Comment: Do both Ethernet conections use static IP?

Comment: Yes. They use different static IPs. @migrc

Comment: Could you post the configuration of both interfaces?

Comment: @migrc I have posted the output of `ifconfig`. Please tell me if more information is needed.

Comment: How do you configure the interfaces, using the GUI or using the terminal?

Comment: @migrc I used the GUI to configure static IP address. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you check that you have enabled the network to be automatically connected?

Comment: How to enable that?

Comment: When you edit the connections in the GUI, in the first tab (named "General" I think) there is an option for that.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: "Every time I boot my computer, eth0 is connected automatically but eht0 is not. And I have to click eth0 manually for connection."

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sorry for the typos. Corrected in my question.